# How do you compile Maven projects with IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm using windows, and I am having trouble understanding how to compile this source. https://github.com/Maxcloud/Mushy

Please if you can help that would be great :)

I think the Readme expects you to be using ubuntu or a linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `File | New | Project from Existing Sources` to import a maven project in IntelliJ. See also [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using intelliJ you can use the maven tab located to the right of your IDE and within that you will have access to all the maven commands, specifically `install` for building your dependencies.

**NOTE*
You will need a valid POM and you will have to tell IntelliJ about it if it doesn't know.

Comment: where do you specify the POM file?